# grails params sticking on dropdown selection for multi-select dropdown

Tags: javascript, grails, gsp

I have a g:select dropdown which I am using to populate what shows in another g:select dropdown in grails. I am populating the second dropdown via a javascript onchange call in the first dropdown. this then manipulates which elements g:select is shown and which is hidden.

There are 3 dropdowns in total which are all set to display: none until the selection is made from the first dropdown.

This second dropdown is then used to determine the params value that is exported from the form.

My issue lies in the params sticking when the second dropdown value is changed. When I select and export a value the first time and sometimes the second time from different dropdowns I get the correct export. Then on the third time the previous value will be exported instead of a new value.

I have tried clearing out the element value each time that select changes and am at a loss as to how to reset the params at this stage. I will post my code below. Any help is appreciated:

g:select gsp code:

```
<g:form>
<table>
    <tbody>

    <tr class="prop3">
        <td>
            <g:select id="target" name="componentchoice"
                      from="${['Export by Name', 'Export by Age', 'Export by Identifier']}"
                      noSelection="${['null': 'Please Choose...']}"
                      onchange="JavaScript:changeList()"/>
        </td>
        <td id="nameComponent" style="display: none">
            <g:select name="name"
                      from="${User.list().findAll {
                          it.name
                      }*.name.sort().unique()}"
                      noSelection="${['null': 'Please Choose...']}"
                      onchange="getElementValues()"/>
        </td>
        <td id="ageComponent" style="display: none">
            <g:select name="age"
                      from="${UserAge.list(sort: 'age')}"
                      noSelection="${['null': 'Please Choose...']}"
                      onchange="getElementValues()"/>
        </td>
        <td id="identifierComponent" style="display: none">
            <g:select name="identifier"
                      from="${Identifier.list().findAll {
                          it.identifier
                      }*.identifier.sort().unique()}"
                      noSelection="${['null': 'Please Choose...']}"
                      onchange="getElementValues()"/>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="prop3">
        <td valign="top" class="name">
            <g:actionSubmit value="Export" action="exportChoice"/>
        </td>
    </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function getElementValues() {
    var visName = document.getElementsByName('name')[0].value;
    var visAge = document.getElementsByName('age')[0].value;
    var visID = document.getElementsByName('identifier')[0].value;
    console.log(visName);
    console.log(visAge);
    console.log(visID);
    visName.value = null;
    visAge.value = null;
    visID.value = null;
}
function changeList() {
    var choice = document.getElementById('target').value;
    var visName = document.getElementById('nameComponent');
    var visAge = document.getElementById('ageComponent');
    var visID = document.getElementById('identifierComponent');
    console.log('Change list is called');

    if (choice == 'Export by Name') {
        visName.style.display = "block";
        visID.style.display = "none";
        visAge.style.display = "none";
    }
    if (choice == 'Export by Age') {
        visAge.style.display = "block";
        visName.style.display = "none";
        visID.style.display = "none";
    }
    if (choice == 'Export by Identifier') {
        visID.style.display = "block";
        visAge.style.display = "none";
        visName.style.display = "none";
    }
}

</script>
```

Controller Code:

```
def exportChoice = { 
def choice = null 
if (params.name && params.name != 'null') {
  choice = User.findAllByName(params.name) 
} else if (params.age && params.age != 'null') {
  choice = UserAge.findAllByAge(params.age)  
} else if (params.identifier && params.identifier != 'null') {
  choice = Identifier.findAllByIdentifier(params.networkIdentifier) 
}

if (!choice) { 
  flash.message = "Unable to find Choice - Try refreshing if problem persists"
  redirect action: 'index'
} else {
  try {
    log.info "Writing Report to output Stream"
    def workbook = new ExcelExport(choice).workbook 
    if (params.name && params.name != 'null') { 
      response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename='${params.name}.xls'")
    } else if (params.age && params.age != 'null') {
      response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename='${params.age}.xls'")
    } else if (params.identifier && params.identifier != 'null') {
      response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename='${params.identifier}.xls'")
    }
    response.contentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
    workbook.write(response.outputStream)
    log.info "Flushing Stream"
    response.outputStream.flush()

  } catch (Exception e) {
    def errorMessage = "Error While Creating Excel (${e.message})"
    log.error errorMessage, GrailsUtil.sanitize(e)
    flash.message = errorMessage
    redirect action: 'index'
  }
}
```

}

Comment: What do you mean by _exported from the form_? Just usual form submit? And what is _exported second or third time_? why do you do this multiple times? Apart from that - if you are clicking "back" in the browser, the previous value might be cached. Do you check in the controller all the params passed by the form? (just do `println params` to see if you have one or multiple passed (i.e. name AND age).

Comment: Hi Mikelis. Yes you are correct I mean i am using a form submit as my export function. So there are multiple ways you can export, by name, age or identifier, which all have different lists associated with them. There is no clicking back in the browser when this is done. I have an if else in my controller which checks for the correct params when the submit action is hit and am not seeing any inconsistencies on the Controller side.

Comment: Can you post that controller method's code?

Comment: Hi Mikelis. I have added in the controller code above.

Comment: Did you try printing all the params to see if form takes more than one?

Comment: Hi Mikelis, yes I have and I am only seeing one parameter each time.